# Call a controller

Tags: angularjs

I know it's possible to "extend" a controller in module A from another controller in module A using the [`$controller()`-Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller).

But how do I extend from a controller in **another module**?

Comment: Could you please show what you mean by extending a controller from another controller, with code? Whatever that means, why do you thing modules have anything to do with it?

Comment: By adding your module 1 as dependency in your module 2?

Comment: did you mean extending classes with TypeScript, smth like this - https://gist.github.com/esfand/9569523 ?